# What does this websocket api means?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I have created spring boot websocket project. I want to know what does

> localhost:9090/gs-guide-websocket/parm1/param2/websocket

This Api means?

here i know 'gs-guide-websocket' is my websocket end point but what is the rest of all?

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}
```

Controller.java

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

In the about Url what is the sender identity and whom we are sending?
Code is working fine.

Comment: for -1 please let me know what is wrong so can elaborate more clearly

Comment: For simplecity you can consider localhost:9090/gs-guide-websocket/712/a50pfxbq/websocket as localhost:9090/user/getuser/712/username

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean with `param1` and `param2`, where do you get that from? I see no references of `param1` and `param2` within your code.

Comment: @g00glen00b i changed the parameter as for param1 their was 210 and param2 was some hex code like 'rhy42ja1' so for simplicity i changed it to param1 and param2, as some people have downvoted for original url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@MessageMapping` annotation ensures that if a message is sent to `destination "/hello"`, then the `greeting()` method is called.

After the 1 second delay, the `greeting()` method creates a Greeting object and returns it. The return value is broadcast to all subscribers to `"/topic/greetings"` as specified in the `@SendTo` annotation.

Refer [This Example](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring)

Comment: I have edited the URL above to param1 and param2 can you tell me what is param1 and param2 will be,as i am using this url for android app. android natively does not support for STOMP client.

Comment: No doubt you have added param(s) but URL depends on what operation you want to perform. BTW by which URL you are going to start it?

Comment: lets consider i want to subscribe to /topic/greetings and want to send message to /app/hello, then what will be the url. Please help me